# xamarin ios custom back button differs between 11 and 10.3

Tags: c#, user-interface, xamarin.ios

I am using a custom back button in my application.

Code to generate the button

```
protected UIBarButtonItem CreateBackButton(string localizationKey, EventHandler handler)
{
    UIImage image = UIImage.FromBundle("BackIcon");

    UIButton customButton = new UIButton(UIButtonType.Custom);
    customButton.SetTitle(NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString(localizationKey, null), UIControlState.Normal);
    customButton.SetImage(image.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate), UIControlState.Normal);
    customButton.BackButtonStyle();

    customButton.TouchUpInside += handler;

    var backButton = new UIBarButtonItem(customButton);

    return backButton;
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
    internal static UIButton BackButtonStyle(this UIButton button)
    {
        button.SetTitleColor(ViewModelHelper.FromHex(PrimaryAppColor).ToNative(), UIControlState.Normal);
        button.TintColor = ViewModelHelper.FromHex(PrimaryAppColor).ToNative();

        return button;
    }
```

PrimaryAppColor is a simple RGB string value in hex style.

The code is called in the "ViewDidLoad" like following:

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        ---Snipped---

        this.NavigationItem.SetHidesBackButton(true, false);
        this.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = this.CreateBackButton("localizedBackKey", this.OnBackButtonPressed);

        ---Snipped---
    }
```

Pls see attached screen shots for the result. First one is the expected look!

[image: iOS 11]

[image: iOS 10.3]

Does any of you have an idea why it is showing the View title and my custom button.

THX

Comment: Please show the code in method `BackButtonStyle`, did you set frame or set constraint?

Comment: Updated the post.
No the method does not contain any frame or constraint data. It just applies colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you forgot to set frame on the Button , so the text and image got overlap.

#### Solution:

```
customButton.Frame = new CGRect(0,0,100,44);
```

Comment: Hi Cole, I just tried your suggestion, but sadly no changes... I don't think that it is a problem with the size of the button, but more with the position... If you look closer you will notice that the button is far more right then the default back button.

Comment: Try to set frame on button . `customButton.Frame  = new CGRect(0,0,100,44);`

Comment: That just solved it, THX.
Do you have any idea why the button is much further right than the original back. Is it because I set the LeftButton and not the backButton property?

Comment: @Christoph you can set `ImageEdgeInsets`, try this: `button.ImageEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0, -10, 0, 0);`